# How do I use gpsdecode to output the results of gpscat in a readable manner?

Tags: embedded, stderr, gpsd

I am connected to a processor with GPS attached through a USB-serial port. What I've been trying to do is read the GPS data by doing:

```
gpscat /dev/ttyS2 | gpsdecode
```

However, it's very slow and after a long time it outputs this:

```
130 root@gw-0317STLG0067 ~ # gpscat /dev/ttyS2 | gpsdecode            
:(
{"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","vdop":1.20,"hdop":1.20,"pdop":1.80,"satellites":[{"PRN":29,"el":28,"az":79,"ss":39,"used":false},{"PRN":31,"el":18,"az":204,"ss":18,"used":false}]}
```

When I kill the process, this is what it outputs:

```
close failed in file object destructor: 
sys.excepthook is missing 
lost sys.stderr
```

Is this the right command to use? If so, what's the problem?

Edit ---- New

> Output{"class":"TPV","device":"stdin","mode":2,"lat":50.782431667,"lon":6.076753333}
>   {"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","satellites":[{"PRN":27,"el":86,"az":124,"ss":30,"used":false}]}
>   {"class":"TPV","device":"stdin","mode":2,"lat":50.782431667,"lon":6.076753333}
>   {"class":"TPV","device":"stdin","mode":2,"lat":50.782431667,"lon":6.076753333}
>   {"class":"TPV","device":"stdin","mode":2,"lat":50.782431667,"lon":6.076753333}
>   {"class":"TPV","device":"stdin","mode":2,"time":"2017-07-17T14:52:13.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":50.782431667,"lon":6.076753333,"track":206.8000,"speed":0.000}
>   {"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","vdop":1.60,"hdop":1.00,"pdop":2.00,"satellites":[{"PRN":7,"el":10,"az":289,"ss":19,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":54,"az":296,"ss":19,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":59,"az":122,"ss":43,"used":false},{"PRN":15,"el":11,"az":38,"ss":43,"used":false},{"PRN":27,"el":84,"az":126,"ss":34,"used":false}]}
>   {"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","vdop":1.60,"hdop":1.00,"pdop":2.00,"satellites":[{"PRN":7,"el":10,"az":289,"ss":19,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":54,"az":296,"ss":19,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":59,"az":122,"ss":43,"used":false},{"PRN":15,"el":11,"az":38,"ss":43,"used":false},{"PRN":27,"el":84,"az":126,"ss":34,"used":false},{"PRN":27,"el":84,"az":126,"ss":34,"used":false}]}
>   {"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","vdop":1.60,"hdop":1.00,"pdop":2.00,"satellites":[{"PRN":7,"el":10,"az":288,"ss":17,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":55,"az":296,"ss":22,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":60,"az":120,"ss":41,"used":false},{"PRN":15,"el":10,"az":37,"ss":45,"used":false},{"PRN":16,"el":35,"az":188,"ss":25,"used":false},{"PRN":18,"el":46,"az":70,"ss":40,"used":false},{"PRN":21,"el":23,"az":71,"ss":38,"used":false},{"PRN":26,"el":10,"az":175,"ss":24,"used":false},{"PRN":27,"el":84,"az":126,"ss":33,"used":false}]}
>   {"class":"SKY","device":"stdin","vdop":1.60,"hdop":1.00,"pdop":2.00,"satellites":[{"PRN":7,"el":10,"az":288,"ss":17,"used":false},{"PRN":8,"el":55,"az":296,"ss":22,"used":false},{"PRN":10,"el":60,"az":120,"ss":41,"used":false},{"PRN":15,"el":10,"az":37,"ss":45,"used":false},{"PRN":16,"el":35,"az":188,"ss":25,"used":false},{"PRN":18,"el":46,"az":70,"ss":40,"used":false},{"PRN":21,"el":23,"az":71,"ss":38,"used":false},{"PRN":26,"el":10,"az":175,"ss":24,"used":false},{"PRN":27,"el":84,"az":126,"ss":33,"used":false},{"PRN":70,"el":14,"az":23,"ss":25,"used":false},{"PRN":86,"el":39,"az":82,"ss":32,"used":true},{"PRN":65,"el":0,"az":174,"ss":19,"used":false},{"PRN":71,"el":47,"az":70,"ss":29,"used":true},{"PRN":72,"el":35,"az":142,"ss":29,"used":true}]}

Answer (score 1):

> If so, what's the problem?

It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12790328/4957508) as though you're killing the gpsdecode process, which *was* reading gpscat's output. When it stopped reading, the output buffer for gpscat filled up. When the kill signal got to the gpscat process, python tried to close the non-empty output handle, it failed with that message, as seen in the linked Stack Overflow Q&A.

To avoid this particular error, you could try killing the gpscat process instead of the gpsdecode process.

Comment: But for the output before I killed the process, it's not outputting anything readable for me. Is this what's supposed to happen?

Comment: [It says](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gpsdecode.1.html) it outputs json, which seems to be what happened; what did you expect?

Comment: Ok I just retried and got some new output which I updated in my question. However it seems very inconsistent. Sometimes there's TPV, other times there's SKY. If I want coordinates, I'll use TPV right? But why does TPV and SKY each come randomly?

Comment: Ok I just retried and got some new output which I updated in my question. However it seems very inconsistent. Sometimes there's TPV, other times there's SKY. If I want coordinates, I'll use TPV right? But why does TPV and SKY each come randomly?

Comment: I don't know anything about gpsdecode; maybe try one of their [mailing lists](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/#mailing-lists) ?